# Salesforce CLI command to retrieve everything?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I created an app with some classes, UI elements, and some other stuff.  I created a package with everything I have created and need to move this to a different instance from my current dev instance for testing and releasing.  Is it possible to download every items as specified in my package using Salesforce CLI in Visual Studio Code?

Follow up question is what is the command to then upload everything in the new instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either a shell script/command or the UI.

To retrieve a package in bash/powershell/cmd:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "My Package Name"
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use the "project from manifest" option in VS Code. Create a package.xml file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://sforce.soap.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>My Package Name</members>
    <name>Package</name>
  </types>
  <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

To deploy to a new org:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app
```

Or in VS Code, right-click on the force-app folder, and click "SFDX: Deploy to Org".

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much